# HTML Parsing of Div data is giving wrong results

Tags: jquery

Using Jquery each function , i am parsing a div data called as myordersdiv

This is my complete program as shown below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var name;
var products = [];
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.each($('#myordersdiv ul'), function(i, elem) {
        name = $(elem).find("label").text();
        if (name != 'undefined') {
            //Creating product array 
            products.push({
                'name': name
            });
        }
    });
    var orderjson = JSON.stringify(products);
    console.log(orderjson);

});

 </script>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="myordersdiv" style="display: block;">
      <ul>
         <div id="ordersdiv" style="">
            <div id="addtoordersdiv71">
               <div class="prd-items-detials">
                  <ul>
                     <li class="head">
                        <form>
                           <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-mini-0" id="71">
                           <label class="testtt" for="checkbox-mini-0">Regular, 50 Ml</label>
                        </form>
                     </li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </ul>
   </div>
</body>

</html>
```

When i ran the above program the Output is

```
[{"name":"Regular, 50 Ml"},{"name":"Regular, 50 Ml"}]
```

which is showing two elements under the array .

But i have got only one element of Regular, 50 Ml under the myordersdiv

Could anybody please tell me why is that  i am getting it two elements ??

THis is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/GStDU/

Answer (score 3):

You have two `ul` inside of `#myordersdiv`, so `each` iterates twice. Over the outer `ul` and over the inner `ul`.

What you maybe want is the selector `$("#myordersdiv > ul")`. This one only hits the `ul`, which are direct children of `#myordersdiv`.

Comment: Working perfectly fine , i was struggling to find the root cause for this  since 3 hours , thank you very much .

Comment: Hi , could you please tell me why this is failing in this case ?? http://jsfiddle.net/GStDU/1/ (Here it has got two elmenents) the first and second names are being combined .

Comment: You should read a tutorial on CSS selectors and review your html structure. The problem you now have is basically the same problem you had in your main question.